# How to search with Regex on all Spark dataframe columns?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following code with Regex that works perfectly for a column. But I would like to extend the code to search all columns of the dataframe.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("Dog 10H03 ", "10H03"),
        ("cat 09H24 eats cba", "09H24"),
        (" cat 09H24 eats cba", "09H24"),
        ("cba ", "09H45"),
        (" abc", "a09H45a "),
    ],
    ["Animal", "Time"],
)
```

I have that

```
df . filtro ( df.Animal. rlike ( '[AZ] * ice $' ))
```

I wish it:

```
df.where('allcolumns rlike "([^ \t\r\n])[ \t]+$"')
```

Comment: Can you explain what your pattern does ? It's not obviously what it's trying to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need create conditional expression for all the columns.

```
# Generators to form expression dynamically
expression = ''.join([f"{x} rlike '([^ \\t\\r\\n])[ \\t]+$' and " for x in df.columns])[:-4]

df.where(expression).show()
```